# Safari from macOS Catalina not working on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, safari, time-machine, mojave, catalina

I followed this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372144/how-to-downgrade-from-macos-catalina-to-mojave) to downgrade from macOS Catalina to Mojave (without having a Mojave backup). This has worked well, except using the Time Machine backup made in Catalina to restore data to Mojave has resulted in getting a too advanced version of Safari for macOS Mojave:

```
You can’t use this version of the application “Safari” with this version of macOS.
You have macOS 10.14.6. The application requires macOS 10.15 or later.
```

What would be the easiest way to downgrade to a working version of Safari? I am hoping it does not involve reinstalling macOS Mojave.

Comment: Update or reinstall Safari for your computer
: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204416 from https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari. It suggests App Store for older versions, TM  (or otherwise) backup and reinstall macOS only,

Comment: Unfortunately that second link does not contain a macOS Safari download (and has not been updated since 2015). Though I'll try download an OS X version and see if that works and then update it to the latest version that will work on Mojave.

The first link suggests reinstalling the operating system, which I would prefer not to do - it seems an overkill - and I am not entirely sure wiil work, as I have Safari, just a non-functioning version.

Comment: Hi gōshafoc, welcome to Ask Different. I would recommend that you reinstall macOS. It may seem an overkill, but it is the only supported way to restore Safari. Note that the linked article states "If you deleted Safari and don't have a Time Machine backup or other backup, reinstall macOS (...)" so you may want to delete Safari first. Needless to say, just in case something went wrong: before deleting Safari and reinstalling macOS Mojave, back up your Mac.

Comment: Thank you jaume, thank you ankii. You are both right, reinstalling macOS fixed the problem and did not cause any extra problems. It looks like it is no longer possible to download Safari as a stand alone app, so this is the solution.

Comment: I think this will be difficult.  Safari uses a framework.  It's an open source framework, at least it was. Your Safari is going to be using a different framework than it expects.  I suggest you switch to opera.  It imbeds the framework within its app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [jaume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/32815/jaume) and [ankii](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/313842/ankii) suggested in the comments below the question (and as per Apple Support), the way to do it is to reinstall macOS Mojave. I now have the correct version of Safari for Mojave and I don't seem to have gained any new problems doing this.

If anyone comes to this question looking to find a place to download a stand alone version of Safari for macOS, I don't think it exists - though I am happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the safari app from a mac that have Mojave installed then change the name of safari that you copied, finally paste into the app folder :)