# Need a download of Mojave

Tags: macos

Can someone tell me where to get MacOS Mojave?  I have a Mac which I have upgraded to Catalina, and I need to downgrade to run some legacy apps.

Thanks.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374846/can-mojave-be-installed-on-separate-apfs-volume-under-catalina?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373535/can-i-downgrade-to-macos-mojave-if-i-buy-the-new-2019-macbook-pro?rq=1  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372144/how-to-downgrade-from-macos-catalina-to-mojave

Answer (score 3):

Use this link to download macOS Mojave from App Store:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12

Comment: Link-only answers are normally frowned upon, tend to get down-voted and or deleted, however I up voted this because **it actually answers the question asked**! The interesting thing here is, **macOS Catalina** will actually download the **macOS Mojave** installer, where as in e.g. **macOS Mojave** it would not download e.g. **macOS High Sierra** if you hadn't previously downloaded it. With **Apple** switching to using **System Preferences** to download **macOS**, and its updates, things have changed.

Comment: @user349894 True. But you can not install Mojave from Catalina itself. You have to create an USB Stick Mojave Installer.

Comment: modlin, I'm well aware of that!